# Passing String Pointer Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, parameter-passing

I have a simple C function which I would like to pass an array of pointers to various strings.  I am having trouble with the compiler barking at my function call parameters.  Here is simple representation of what I am doing,

**myfunction.h**

```
int myServices(int, char *[]);
```

**myfunction.c**

```
#include <myfunction.h>
int myService(int value, char *strpointer[]) {

   ***

}
```

**mainroutine.c**

```
#include <myfuntion.h>
void main () {

   // Initialize Parameters
   int result;
   int stringcnt;
   char string1[8] = "-st";
   char string2[8] = "-ir";
   char * stringptr[10];

   // Initialize stringptr
   stringptr[0] = string1;
   stringptr[1] = string2;
   stringcnt = 2;

   // Call Service
   result = myService(stringcnt, stringptr); <== gcc issue with stringptr

}
```

The C compiler keeps giving me a "invalid use of member (did you forget the '&'?" with the stringptr in the myService call.  I tried '&' and '*' with stringptr in the myService call in the main routine with no luck.  Any ideas.

Comment: Few things I notice... `int myServices(int char *[]);` `int myService(int value, char *strpointer[])` Don't line up? Which is it?

Comment: Missing a comma.  Edited source.

Comment: `void main (argc, argv[])` -- Truly? That's what your book said?

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes.  I just typed a representative sample without using an IDE.  Just trying to keep the code focused on the problem.

Comment: Posting a compilable version of the problem helps us focus on the true issues.  Perhaps, re-edit to true, minimal code.

Comment: Either `int main()` or `int main( int argc, char * argv[] )` (or `char * * argv`, which would be "more correct" but which I dislike for personal reasons). As for coming up with a [mcve], the first thing you'd do is to do away with the multiple files. Yes, that's how you want it to look in your project. No, it is not related to the question you're asking here. Reduce the workload of people trying to reproduce your problem to a minimum. Quite often this already helps resolving some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and notices a few things: first of all in your header file you didn't define the arguments properly (case of the missing coma), and likewise your main entry point did not have the proper return type (needs to be int) nor arguments (int argc, char *argv[]). I've made the changes and attached them below:

```
 // func.h

int myService(int, char*[]);
```

Then the function code:

```
// func.c

#include "func.h"

int myService(int value, char *strpointer[]) {
        // your code here
        return 0;
}



// prog.c
```

-

```
#include "func.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

   // Initialize Parameters
   int result;
   int stringcnt;
   char string1[8] = "-st";
   char string2[8] = "-ir";
   char * stringptr[10];

   // Initialize stringptr
   stringptr[0] = string1;
   stringptr[1] = string2;
   stringcnt = 2;

   // Call Service
   result = myService(stringcnt, stringptr);
   return 0;
}
```

I compiled this using the command `gcc -o prog.o prog.c func.c` with no errors and smooth execution. Hope this works for you

Comment: I verified my code against yours and found it to be equivalent.  I removed the "result =" from the myService call in the "main" and the compiler stopped barking.  I have the correct return integer value in myService.  Not sure why this is happening but I have enough to continue debugging.  Thanks for the help.